# outputschema using python udf in Apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

My python udf returns a list of tuples like this:

```
[(0.01, 12), (0.02, 6), (0.03, 12), (0.04, 19), (0.05, 29), (0.06, 42)]
```

The above is printed into and copied from the mapper's stdout.

The two values in the tuples are casted to float and int respectively. I also printed out the type and it's indeed correctly casted.

```
(<type 'float'>, <type 'int'>)
```

Here is the decorator `@outputSchema("stats:bag{improvement:tuple(percent:float,entityCount:int)}")`

Here is the error message:

> Error: java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Datum (0.01,12) is not in union
>   ["null",{"type":"record","name":"TUPLE_1","fields":[{"name":"percent","type":["null","float"],"doc":"autogenerated
>   from Pig Field
>   Schema","default":null},{"name":"entityCount","type":["null","int"],"doc":"autogenerated
>   from Pig Field Schema","default":null}]}] at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:479)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:442)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:422)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:269)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1754)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused
>   by: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Datum (0.01,12) is not in union
>   ["null",{"type":"record","name":"TUPLE_1","fields":[{"name":"percent","type":["null","float"],"doc":"autogenerated
>   from Pig Field
>   Schema","default":null},{"name":"entityCount","type":["null","int"],"doc":"autogenerated
>   from Pig Field Schema","default":null}]}] at
>   org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:263) at
>   org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroRecordWriter.write(PigAvroRecordWriter.java:49)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage.putNext(AvroStorage.java:646)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:136)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOutputFormat.java:95)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:558)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:105)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:477)
>   ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Datum (0.01,12) is
>   not in union
>   ["null",{"type":"record","name":"TUPLE_1","fields":[{"name":"percent","type":["null","float"],"doc":"autogenerated
>   from Pig Field
>   Schema","default":null},{"name":"entityCount","type":["null","int"],"doc":"autogenerated
>   from Pig Field Schema","default":null}]}] at
>   org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.resolveUnion(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:132)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.writeUnion(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:111)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.write(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:82)
>   at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeArray(GenericDatumWriter.java:131)
>   at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:68)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.write(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.writeUnion(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:113)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.write(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:82)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.writeRecord(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:378)
>   at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:66)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.PigAvroDatumWriter.write(PigAvroDatumWriter.java:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:58)
>   at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:257)
>   ...

Anyone know what I did wrong in the schema?

Comment: From initial observation you have generated bag of tuples, but while writing it you may be writing as flat tuples which may causing the issue. If you can post code snippet then we can investigate issue further. Thanks!!

Comment: Actually, I printed the pythonudf output to the stdout, which I copied from the mapper to the beginning of the question. The entire pythonudf is rather long, so it can be distracting..

Comment: After a lot of testing, I’m inclined to believing this is a bug of pig. If anyone has encountered this before, can you share how you solved the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Try:
`@outputSchema('b1:bag{t:(f1:float, f2:int)}')`

Also make sure your python UDF is actually returning list of tuples. Is the stdout print mentioned in the question an intermediate log  or the return output from the UDF?

Comment: The stdout print was printed out right before the return statement like this -> `print(result)  return result` I just tried the suggested schema, and got the same error :(

Comment: If possible, can you share a sample input&code that reproduce your issue?